# Getting number value out of input and calculating

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to debug the following code:

```
    window.onload = function() {
// defining buttons
        document.getElementById("TriangleButton");
        document.getElementById("ParallelogramButton");
        document.getElementById("TrapezoidButton");
        document.getElementById("CircleButton");
// where answer gets shown
        document.getElementById("questionAnswer");
// base, base2, height and radius input values
        var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
        var base2 = document.getElementById("base2").value;
        var height = document.getElementById("Height").value;
        var radius = document.getElementById("Radius").value;

// defining equations

        let circle = (3.14 * (radius * radius));
        let trapezoid = (1/2 * height * (base + base2));
        let parallelogram = (base * height);
        let triangles = (base * height/2)

        // actions when buttons get clicked

        TriangleButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
          questionAnswer.innerText = triangles
        })
        ParallelogramButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
          questionAnswer.innerText = parallelogram
        })   
        TrapezoidButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
          questionAnswer.innerText = trapezoid
        })
        CircleButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            questionAnswer.innerText = circle
        })
    }
```

HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
      <title>Daniel the 4th</title> // title of webpage
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>  // linking js to html  
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>What are you calculating?</p> // buttons
        <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
        <p id="TriangleButton">Triangle Area</p>  
        <p id="ParallelogramButton">Parallelogram Area</p>
        <p id="TrapezoidButton">Trapezoid Area</p>
        <p id="CircleButton">Circle Area</p>
        </div>
        // number inputs
        <p>Enter necessary numbers here:</p>
        <p>Base: <input type="number" id="base"></p>
        <p>Base 2: <input type="number" id="base2"></p>
        <p>Height: <input type="number" id="Height"></p>
        <p>Radius: <input type="number" id="Radius"></p>
           // answer 
        <p id="questionAnswer"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To get the best help here, please add a description of what this code should do, what it actually does (not) do, and any errors/problems that you think readers should know about.

Comment: *"I have been trying to debug the following code"* What happened then? Did you run into a roadblock? Are you stuck on something?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```js
window.onload = function() {
    // defining buttons
    document.getElementById("TriangleButton");
    document.getElementById("ParallelogramButton");
    document.getElementById("TrapezoidButton");
    document.getElementById("CircleButton");

    // where answer gets shown
    document.getElementById("questionAnswer");

    var base, base2, height, radius;
    function get_newvalue(){
        // base, base2, height and radius input values
        base   = document.getElementById("base").value;
        base2  = document.getElementById("base2").value;
        height = document.getElementById("Height").value;
        radius = document.getElementById("Radius").value;
    }
    
    // actions when buttons get clicked
    TriangleButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        get_newvalue();
        questionAnswer.innerText = (base * height/2)
    })
    ParallelogramButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        get_newvalue();
        questionAnswer.innerText = (base * height);
    })   
    TrapezoidButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        get_newvalue();
        questionAnswer.innerText = (1/2 * height * (base + base2));
    })
    CircleButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        get_newvalue();
        questionAnswer.innerText = (3.14 * (radius * radius));
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Daniel the 4th</title> <!-- title of webpage -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script> <!-- linking js to html   -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- number inputs -->
        <p>Enter necessary numbers here:</p>
        <p>Base: <input type="number" id="base"></p>
        <p>Base 2: <input type="number" id="base2"></p>
        <p>Height: <input type="number" id="Height"></p>
        <p>Radius: <input type="number" id="Radius"></p>

        <p>What are you calculating?</p> <!-- buttons -->
        <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
            <button id="TriangleButton">Triangle Area</button>
            <button id="ParallelogramButton">Parallelogram Area</button>
            <button id="TrapezoidButton">Trapezoid Area</button>
            <button id="CircleButton">Circle Area</button>
        </div>
        <!-- answer  -->
        <p id="questionAnswer"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and have got 0 for all answers. because you have calculated answers in the "window.onload" event and they will be displayed as the answer.

You should get the values of inputs in each button click. then calculate the answer.

I have changed your code and you can see and run that below.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  // defining buttons
  document.getElementById("TriangleButton");
  document.getElementById("ParallelogramButton");
  document.getElementById("TrapezoidButton");
  document.getElementById("CircleButton");
        
  // where answer gets shown
  document.getElementById("questionAnswer");  

  // TriangleButton action
  TriangleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    const base = document.getElementById("base").value
    const height = document.getElementById("Height").value
    const triangles = (base * height/2)
  
    questionAnswer.innerText = triangles
    
  })
  
  // ParallelogramButton action
  ParallelogramButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
    const base = document.getElementById("base").value
    const height = document.getElementById("Height").value
    const parallelogram = (base * height)
    
    questionAnswer.innerText = parallelogram
    
  })
  
  // TrapezoidButton action
  TrapezoidButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    const base = document.getElementById("base").value
    const base2 = document.getElementById("base2").value
    const height = document.getElementById("Height").value
    const trapezoid = (1/2 * height * (base + base2))
    
    questionAnswer.innerText = trapezoid
     
  })
  
  // CircleButton action
  CircleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    const radius = document.getElementById("Radius").value
    const circle = (3.14 * (radius * radius))
    questionAnswer.innerText = circle
      
  })
  
}
```

```html
<p>What are you calculating?</p> // buttons
<div id="buttons" class="buttons">
  <p id="TriangleButton">Triangle Area</p>  
  <p id="ParallelogramButton">Parallelogram Area</p>
  <p id="TrapezoidButton">Trapezoid Area</p>
  <p id="CircleButton">Circle Area</p>
</div>

// number inputs
<p>Enter necessary numbers here:</p>
<p>Base: <input type="number" id="base"></p>
<p>Base 2: <input type="number" id="base2"></p>
<p>Height: <input type="number" id="Height"></p>
<p>Radius: <input type="number" id="Radius"></p>
// answer 

<p id="questionAnswer"></p>
```